# Two-dimensional AR modelling and linear predication with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, correlation, speech-synthesis

I'm working on two-dimensional AR modelling and using the algorithms 
from Matlab. In matlab there is a commend LPC which can compute the LP coefficients. How can I integrated to two dimension for image ?

[image]

The matlab code for one dimension signal is

```
[a]=lpc(signal,order)
est_signal = filter([0 -a(2:end)],1,signal);
error = signal-est_signal;
```

However, I dont how I can integrate for image which is 2D.

Comment: Could you maybe give an example (image plus code using lpc) to show what you are doing? Also what exactly do you want to achieve? What do you want to integrate?

Comment: Dear @Trilarion I have revised my question.